# What to do with an answer that is revealed to be incorrect in the comments?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, accepted-answer

Please take a look at [What is the HTTP Referer if the link is clicked in an <iframe>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468335/what-is-the-http-referer-if-the-link-is-clicked-in-an-iframe/8496491?noredirect=1#comment52138108_8496491) .

There is an answer there that is mostly incorrect, which is stated by the OP in the comment, but it has been accepted nevertheless and upvoted a few times.

I tried to edit the answer to make it correct but my edit was rejected.

**Is that ok? Should I really leave it like that? What should we do with answers that are incorrect unless you read and follow also all/some of the comments?**

PS This is my first question on Meta, please don't be too harsh if I do it the wrong way. :)

Comment: Downvote. Provide your own answer. A better answer would briefly restate the problem and add some more up-to-date information.

Comment: It's hardly a stunning mega-terrible problem for someone to sort out. Is it worth the effort? Is the question that useful (I have no clue about that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you should strive to correct the answer - this is one of the reasons why the Stack Exchange network allows communal edits.

However there is a bit more to this one than it initially appears. Even if the answer was corrected there may be some discrepancies between different versions of the same browser, these differences should be included in the answer. Also, submitting edits that drastically change a post are discouraged (if you had enough rep you could just outright edit it into shape).

So if you really want to "fix" it my suggestion would be that you create a new answer that is more canonical than the existing one. There is no guarantee that the OP will reverse their answer mark, but at least there will be a correct answer.

If you were to do this then the [pre-existing duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2324202/109702) could be closed as the latter question is better.