# What to do with partially incorrect comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I commented on a question but later someone other possessing more knowledge corrected me. I found that he indeed is correct, but the doubt I have is what I should do with that partially incorrect comment. Should I delete it so that some other may not get the misleading answer? But if I do that, the comment below will seem to be absurd.

Here's the [link to an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690291/shell-script-sh-file-to-read-a-line-and-copy-specific-value-to-another-text-f?noredirect=1#comment64760704_38690291). I did accept the mistake in my part but it was not absolutely incorrect as it did give some hint to a potential answer.

I did go through [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303023/what-to-do-with-an-answer-that-is-revealed-to-be-incorrect-in-the-comments) but I feel that my question is a bit different, though similar.

Answer (score 2):

A comment is **never** an answer or part of an answer. Comments are there as a tool to briefly discuss the content; getting mistakes cleared up, requesting further additions, etc. They should be, by their very nature, possible to remove without remorse at any time - and that will happen, as soon as someone flags a comment for any reason there is a high chance it will be removed.

So yes, feel free to remove it - or feel free to leave it; nobody really cares to be honest. The fact that the remainder of the comments make less sense because of its removal has absolutely no bearing on the situation, if there is valuable information in there somewhere it should have been made part of the question or an answer.

If you scan through existing questions you'll find quite a lot of "broken" comment chains. Heck even without removal that already happens as when the number of comments increases, the site starts to automatically hide comments based on their score creating rather amusing but very disjointed discussions. It's not a problem.